# Getting "column can not be null" error in symfony2 and Doctrine app

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have class country and this in my constructor

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->isDeleted = false;

        $this->setLastUpdatedBy(99);
        $this->setCreatedBy(99);

    }
```

But when i fill the form then i get this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'createdAt' cannot be null

IS there anything lese i need to do to make that field default date time

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using php 5.3+

Comment: I am using php 5.3.3. but anything in constructor is not working. when i put that in `prePersist()` then it worked but not in constructor